# TinyMCE deletes content between <a></a> tags, why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have following code:

```
<div class='o-main__subsection'> <h5 class = 'u-text-blue
has-popup-toggle'>smth <a class='c-popup-toggle'
id='smth' data-name='smth' data-title='smth'
data-imgurl='assets/i/content/smth.jpg' href='javascript:void(0)'><i
class='fa fa-camera'></i></a></h5>
<p>text</p>    </div><!-- o-main__subsection -->
```

When i put this code inside tinymce editor as source code, it removes everything between `<a></a>` tags. It's on ruby on rails 4 application. How i can fix this?

Comment: You don't have a text except an icon <i></i> inside <a></a> in the first place. How do you expect to show any text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your TinyMCE configuration to allow the `<i>` tag and also allow attributes on the tag to be valid.

By default TinyMCE will convert `<b>` to `<strong>` and `<i>` to `<em>`.  You can change this in the TinyMCE configuration as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: [ ... ],
  toolbar: " ... ",
  formats: {
    bold: { inline: 'b' },
    italic: { inline: 'i' }
  },
  extended_valid_elements: 'b[*],i[*]'
});
```

You need both the `formats` and the `extended_valid_elements` changes to get this to work.

The other issue is your href has JavaScript in it so TinyMCE's XSS filters are getting involved.  If you change the code to the following you won't trigger the XSS filters:

```
<div class="o-main__subsection">
  <h5 class="u-text-blue has-popup-toggle">smth 
    <a id="smth" class="c-popup-toggle" href="#" 
       data-name="smth" data-title="smth" 
       data-imgurl="assets/i/content/smth.jpg">
      <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
    </a>
  </h5>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this in action: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/a1faab

Comment: It's still removing content between tags

Comment: Using the fiddle when I copy the example code I provided and paste it into the code view no data is modified or lost.